# As If The Function Didn't Exist.. (Spooky)

Tags: python

This function is supposed to (A) Store the contents of a file into a list, (B) Check to see if the contents of the list are the same as the contents of another list. But, when I run the program, nothing appears at all. It is as if the function wasn't in my code.....

```
while True:
    try:
        fileObject = open("studentAnswers.txt", "r")
        index = 0
        correctAnswers = ["B", "D", "A", "A", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "D", \
"B", "C", "D", "A", "D", "C", "C", "B", "D", "A"]
        studentAnswers = []
        fileObject.readlines()

        for line in fileObject:
            studentAnswers.insert(index, line)
            index += 1
        index = 0

        for element in studentAnswers:
            if element == correctAnswers[index]:
                print("Question #", index, "is correct!")
            else:
                print("Question #", index, "is incorrect.")
            index += 1
        fileObject.close()

    except ValueError:
        print("Error.")
        break
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 5):

remove the line :

```
fileObject.readlines()
```

Because what happens is the pointer of your file goes to the end of the file, and when you trying to iterate over it in the next for loop, it is actually doens't have any data inside.

consider the example:

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> output = StringIO.StringIO('aaaa\nbbb\nccc')
>>> output.readlines()
['aaaa\n', 'bbb\n', 'ccc']
>>> output.tell()
12
>>> for line in output:
...   print line
... 
>>> 
>>> output.seek(0)
>>> for line in output:
...   print line
... 
aaaa

bbb

ccc
>>>
```